# Create line chart using (x,y) coordinates

Tags: echarts

I have looked through all the documentation but could not find a way to create a line chart by specifying two points. (x1,y1) (x2,y2). Instead of passing only the y values in the data array, I want to be able to specify the 2 points.

```
 data: [{
          x: 0,
          y: 2
         },
         {
          x: 20
          y: 50
          }
         ]
```

The above obviously does not work. But I'm looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below:

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [[0,2],[20,50]],
        type: 'line'
    }]
};
```

Copy & paste above code [Here](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=line-simple) and run to see demo.

## JsFiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/tilakputta/5aeh8wc4/1/
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works perfectly. This is such a good library but the documentation is so lacking